# How to give Border to list-view in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview

I am developing an application in android java Eclipse having two list view side by side and I want to add border to each **`list-view`**. How can do it? 
Please help me...

Comment: but if you need divider between two listview just have a textview between both listview with width = 1dp and height = fill_parent or as required

Comment: But I want separator like border to right.

Comment: in xml file just add textview with width 1dp and height  = fill_parent and and also set background color that is

Comment: can you paste your xml file that contains two listview

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" ><LinearLayout         android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="433dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="30dp"> **<ListView **
  android:id="@+id/listView1"
 android:layout_width="229dp"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
 android:layout_weight="0.37">

Comment: remaining code:-  </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="667dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.12" >
        </ListView>
   
        
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once try this to have seperator between two list views

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="433dp"
        android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="229dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.37" >
        </ListView>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:background="#FF0000"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_width="667dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.12" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use shape for setting background border for each listview.
below is the sample shape.xml file you can create and set it as background for your listview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#f3f3f3"/>    
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#bfbfbf"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
            android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

if you need rounded corner to your listiew you can use

```
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

even you can set background through xml file as below::

```
 android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

and through code as below:::

```
listview_instance.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
```

Also make sure your project's res/drawable folder contains a shape.xml file.

Comment: Please tell me how you set this shape.xml to background of list view

Comment: listview.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

Comment: place this shape.xml in drawable folder

Comment: but this give me an error `The method setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (int)`

Comment: how you are setting and are you setting to listview object

Comment: `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
`super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
`setContentView(R.layout.main);`
`ArrayAdapter<String> menu1Adapter = new `

`ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);`
 
`ListView menu1=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);`
`menu1.setAdapter(menu1Adapter);`
`menu1Adapter.add("menu1");`
`menu1Adapter.add("menu2");`
`menu1Adapter.add("menu3");`
`menu1Adapter.add("menu4");`

 `menu1.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.shape);`
 
`}`

Comment: thank you for your time and help.One last question can I use **line** to draw line at right side of `list view`?If not any other suggestion?

Comment: i didnt get you what you need

Comment: `Rectangle` draw line a line at four side of `list view` and I want to draw a line at one side(Right side) of `List View`. How can I do it? Using line something else?